# I want to display GoogleMap within Rviz but Rviz does not

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Environment

- Ubuntu 20.04
- ROS Noetic
- Rover : ZED-F9P

### What I want to do

I want to display GoogleMap in Rviz.

### Current status

- Execute the following commands
  referring to the following URL.

https://qiita.com/k-koh/items/91d7ea55cbdfc3d3aaf9

https://github.com/hakuturu583/gps_rviz_plugin

```
cd catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/hakuturu583/gps_rviz_plugin.git
cd ... /
catkin build
```

- Get Google Static Map API key.
- Set the obtained Google Static Map API key in gps_rviz_plugin/config/google_static_map_api_key.yaml.
- Commented out rosbag play in gps_rviz_plugin/launch/gps_rviz_plugin.launch.
- Launch gps_rviz_plugin.launch.

  roslaunch gps_rviz_plugin gps_rviz_plugin.launch
- Add OverlayGpsDisplay of gps_rviz_plugin in rviz and set fix in Topic.

### What is currently happening

Rviz starts up but the map is not showing up.

### Question

1. I have not included the base station information in the steps so far, is there a place to put it?

### Finally

Please help me with any information you know.
And, please let me know if you have any further questions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406134/i-want-to-display-googlemap-within-rviz-but-rviz-does-not./) by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend reviewing tickets on the repository: https://github.com/hakuturu583/gps_rviz_plugin/issues and if you can't find one related to your situation open one there. It could be that there needs to be better documentation, or you could be hitting a bug.

That repository looks to have been last updated 5 years ago, and things many have changed in that time that needs updates.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2022-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [donguri](https://answers.ros.org/users/113638/donguri/) on 2022-09-16**:
Thank you for your appropriate response.

And sorry for the delay in replying.

I was able to solve this issue.

I left out sending base station information to Ubuntu.

```
./str2str -in ntrip://rtk2go.com:2101/[MountPoint] -out serial://ttyACM0:230400
```

However, I get a lot of other errors.

If you know of a solution, we would appreciate it if you could answer our questions as well.

[New question](https://answers.ros.org/question/406507/i-want-to-get-gps-information-in-ros-but-many-errors-occur/)